# Is it possible to create a mysql table with value that auto increments every 1 second ? if yes how to do this?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a table with value that auto increments every 1 second ?  if yes it is appreciated to give a simple example.

Comment: I guess but why would you?

Comment: well. i want to create an entry with a modified time stamp that increases every second so when the page query for it, it gets it like an actual usage of date() function.

Comment: generally i want to make a count down on my website that should be the same for all regions and all time zones. i want the time left to be queried from the data base, so it should be decremented every second.

Comment: That makes no sense to me

Comment: Just store the seed time. Everything else is handled in your application. The regional issue is trivial.

Comment: this is an application-level issue. You would store the timestamp of _when it happened_, retrieve that from the database, and then use whatever application language to subtract the current time from the stored date.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use mysql event with `auto_increment` column in target table

```
CREATE EVENT table_insert
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
DO
   UPDATE inc SET value=value+1 where id=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer but think you did not get what i mean, i want the same tuple(place) to be updated every second.
It will be one table with one column that has one record but this record should be incremented every second. Is this possible ?

Comment: You should modify question as my answer was before your detail in comments

Comment: You can write update query using this event as per your requirements

Comment: well. here is the query i have ran but it did not work the value is still the same every time i refresh the table.

CREATE EVENT table_insert
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
DO
UPDATE `inc` SET `id`=(1),`value`=((SELECT `value` FROM `inc` WHERE `id` = 1)+1)

please tell me if i have done something wrong.
i am a beginner so please be patient with me :)

Comment: your update query is wrong, please test it alone via sql query box, it should be `UPDATE inc SET value=value+1 where id=1`

Comment: please show me your table structure so I can update answer

Comment: here is a picture of my table structure.
https://pictub.club/image/76y1t6

and here is a picture of the entry i want it to be auto incremented every second.
https://pictub.club/image/76yMw8

Comment: ok so my answer now should work

Comment: please note that i used a select statement inside my query to get the value from the table, increase it by 1 then update it. (i think i should do this because i want the same entry to be incremented.)

Comment: The query works, but the value is not updated every second it is always 1.  every time i refresh my db browser the value is the same.

Comment: no need of select statement

Comment: yes i got this :), sorry i didn't know that i can use value itself.

Comment: OH GOOD, it worked at last...
The missed parts was that i should activate the GLOBAL event_scheduler first using this query  (SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;)...

Please add it to your answer to leave it as a complete answer to others.